# incorporating php into button that opens into iFrame

Tags: php

Trying to incorporate php into a button that opens a link into an iframe and am running into troubles.. I keep coming up with unexpected T_STRING error

The code I am trying to incorporate is:

```
echo "      <td width='41' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#C6DEFF'>
<button type='button' 
onClick='document.getElementById('maps').src=\"maps/statsmap.php?q=' . $row['gegevenID'] . '&vID=' .$row['vID'] .'&aID='.$row['aID']."\"'>
View</button></div></td>";
```

Comment: If you are going to concatenate with `'. $stuff .'` you need to use the `'` for your echo... `echo '<td> blah blah'` instead of the `"` you are using. Otherwise you can do `?q=" . $row . "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[You missed a double quote here]**

```
"maps/statsmap.php?q=' ". $row['gegevenID']
                       ^
```

**Modified code.**

```
<?php
echo "<td width='41' align='center' valign='middle' bgcolor='#C6DEFF'>
    <button type='button'
            onClick='document.getElementById('maps').src=\"maps/statsmap.php?q=' ". $row['gegevenID'] . '&vID=' .$row['vID'] .'&aID='.$row['aID']."\"'>
    View</button></div></td>";
```